# Dynamic Python Lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

In the below Python Code, am dynamically create Lists.

```
g['quest_{0}'.format(random(x))] = []
```

where `random(x)` is a random number, how to print the List(get the name of the dynamically created List name?)

Comment: Store the random number (or the whole key) in a variable first?

Comment: It's not a list, it's a dictionary of lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a list of all the keys of your dictionary :

```
list(g.keys())
```

There is nothing different with a regular dictionary because you generate the key dynamically.

Note that you can also put any type of hashable object as a key, such as a tuple :

```
g[('quest', random(x))] = []
```

Which will let you get a list of all your quest numbers easily :

```
[number for tag, number in g.keys() if tag == "quest"]
```

With this technic, you can actually loop through the tag ('quest'), the number and the value in one loop :

```
for (tag, number), value in g.items():
    # do somthing
```

Unpacking is your best friend in Python.

Comment: `list(g.keys)` should be `list(g.keys())` or `list(g)`. `keys()` is unnecessary because dictionaries are iterable and yield keys when they are iterated.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the `g` dictionary with a for loop, like this

```
for key, value in g.items():
   print key, value
```

This will print all the keys and their corresponding lists.